# Range of an integral operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, lebesgue-integral

I tried to determine the range of the integral operator $T\in\mathcal{L}(L^2(0,1))$ given by
$$(Tx)(t) = \int^1_t x(s)ds \text{ for } x \in L^2(0,1), t\in[0,1]$$
but it doesn't sound very logical.
This is my approach to the solution:
\begin{align*}
y(t) = Tx(t) &= \int^1_t x(s)ds\\
             &= \alpha - \int^t_0 x(s)ds ~~~~~(\alpha = \int^1_0 x(s)ds<\infty) \\
\Rightarrow -y'&=x
\end{align*}
Then
\begin{align*}
(Tx)(0) = \alpha <\infty~~~~~ &, ~~~~~(Tx)(1) = 0\\
(Tx)(t) = -(Ty')(t) &= \int^t_1 y'(s)ds = y(t) - y(1) 
\end{align*}
if the integral exist, i.e. $y'(s)$ exists, $y' \in L^2(0,1)$ and $y(1) = 0$.
Therefore
$$\mathcal{R}(T) = \lbrace y \in H^1(0,1)~ \vert ~y(1) = 0\rbrace$$

Comment: It looks like you have $s$ and $t$ switched in the definition of $T$.

Comment: Also, $t\mapsto \int_t^1 x(s)\ \mathsf ds$ need not be differentiable, since we are only assuming $x\in L^2$, not that $x$ is continuous.

Comment: yes, you are right, I mixed up the definition.

Comment: The range is the set of all absolutely continuous functions $f$ such that $f' \in L^{2} ([0,1]) $ and $f(1)=0$.